# Conversion failed with SSRS and not SQL

Tags: sql, reporting-services, int, ssrs-2008-r2, varchar

I have a SQL statement that is made up of temp tables and I have joined them together to make a master table.

Running this works fine but when I try to run the proc in the SSRS report its errors with a

```
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '--' to data type int
```

I have tried all sorts and still nothing works , I do believe that the error does lie somewhere in this temp table

```
create table #DATAIMPORTEDX0SS
(
 [AGENT] varchar(32)
,[Allocated x0] int
)

insert into #DATAIMPORTEDX0SS
([AGENT],[Allocated x0])

Select ui.username [AGENT], count(DISTINCT(ah.accountid)) [Allocated x0]
From [sysdba].[DCLALLOCHIST] ah
inner join [sysdba].[USERINFO] ui ON ah.userid = ui.userid
Where ah.source = 'Scar'
and ah.timesout < 1
and ah.createdate >= @startdate AND ah.createdate <= @enddate
group by ui.username
order by 1
```

does anyone have any ideas??

Comment: Can you try just running the `SELECT` statement in isolation to see what it gives you?

Comment: you have to figure out which field has characters in it...Also You may have a field in SSRS defined as int when it is actually varchar.

Comment: My guess is that your `ah.source` field has the **--** in it.

Comment: Whoops - actually I think it's `ah.timesout` since that's the field in the comparison to an integer.